# Automatic creation of changelog topic does not work

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am using Kafka Streams to create a join of two topics. This join creates automatically changelog topic in Kafka for storing the state. In the broker I have the property *auto.create.topics.enable* set to false.

When I run my application it throws Exception

[2018-03-15 10:36:03,179] ERROR stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Failed to create an active task 0_0:  (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread:666)
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: task [0_0] Could not find partition info for topic: smartEventsCepX-KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000006-store-changelog

When I set the property *auto.create.topics.enable* to true, the changelog topic is created and the problem dissappears. Is it the right behavior? How can I enable creation only for automatic topics?

There is no authorization for accessing Kafka. I am using Kafka 0.10.1.1 (Confluent 3.1.2)

Comment: What version of Kafka Streams are you using? Changelog topics are created using the AdminClient. Their creation should not depend on that setting, as far as I know.

Comment: The version of Kafka Streams is 0.10.1.1. I also read, it should not depend, but it seems that it depends :(

Comment: I don’t remember what the behavior was in that version, unfortunately.

Comment: It is not recommend to enable auto topic creation. AdminClient as added  CP 3.3.0 / AK 0.11.0 -- but it should also work in 0.10.1 (you might hit a bug though). I would recommend to upgrade to a newer version (note, that you don't need to upgrade your brokers for this. Kafka Streams is backward compatible: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/upgrade-guide.html#compatibility)